Movie with a kidnapped child and a social media executive
I'm looking for this movie with a kidnapped child and a social media executive. I remember minor details.
The story involves a man who kidnaps a child in a car and takes them to some kind of farm, basically an open area, and calls the police to connect with, I think, some higher authority, maybe the president.
Some of his social information, acquired by the police, is passed to the founder of a big social networking company, who is somehow involved and chilling in some desert doing yoga or something similar. Based on the info shared by the police, he opens his laptop and searches for the relevant profiles, and says the dialogue (not exactly),

You know the perks of being a founder, you get to enter the god mode.


Do you remember anything about the kidnapping - who the child was? Someone important? Was this futuristic or present time? What language was the film? What country was it set in?

https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/tips-for-asking-movie-tv-identification-questions

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Black Mirror – Season 5, Episode 2, "Smithereens"

You appear to be describing "Smithereens" (Season 5, Episode 2) of the TV series Black Mirror. The social media executive is Smithereen CEO Billy Bauer (played by Topher Grace). (Smithereen is a Twitter-like social media platform.) Billy was indeed on a solitary retreat in what appeared to be a desert location. At one point, he says,

Tipi, really the only good thing about my position is every once in a while I get to invoke... God-mode.

The protagonist, Chris Gillhaney (played by Andrew Scott), kidnaps not a child, but an adult employee of Smithereen. Most of the information you've provided seems to align with the episode's plot.
Episode plot:

Chris Gillhaney (Andrew Scott) is a rideshare driver in London. He has sex with Hayley (Amanda Drew), a woman from his group therapy, who has been trying to guess the password to her late daughter's Persona account to find out what led to her suicide. One day, Chris picks up Jaden (Damson Idris), an employee at the social media company Smithereen. Chris abducts him at gunpoint but is furious upon discovering that he is a newly joined intern. A police officer sees Jaden in the back seat with a bag over his head and pursues with her partner. In the chase, Chris veers to avoid two teenage cyclists and stalls the car in a field. An additional contingent of police arrive, led by CS Linda Grace (Monica Dolan).
Chris aims to speak with Smithereen CEO Billy Bauer (Topher Grace). He sends a picture of Jaden at gunpoint to Jaden's superior. Word gets to COO Penelope Wu (Ruibo Qian) in the U.S., who speaks to Chris. However, Billy is on a solitary retreat. As police visit Chris's listed address, Smithereen gather much more information through Chris's social media profiles. Formerly a teacher, Chris lost his fiancée Tamsin in a car accident with a drunk driver three years earlier and has been planning a kidnapping for weeks. […]

Episode trailer:




Thanks a lot @galacticninja...I was not able to recall this since last 6-7 months..LLMa were also not helpful
